# Laravel: Auto populate dropdown select with AJAX is returned undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, cascadingdropdown

So I have tried auto populated dropdown in Laravel. I'm on the half way to complete this, I think so.. So basically I have **3 select dropdown list** which is dependent on the first dropdown. the second dropdown list is return as expected, but the other one / the third dropdown is returned **undefined** list. I haven't find the solution or any clue to fix this. I hope I get the appropriate hints or directions to solve this. Thank You

Here's my dropdown in View

```
                 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nm_cust" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nama Customer</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select name="nm_cust" id="nm_cust" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                            @foreach ($customer['data'] as $cust)
                                <option value="{{ $cust->nm_cust }}">{{ $cust->nm_cust }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="alamat" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alamat</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select name="alamat" id="alamat" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="no_psn" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nomor Pemesanan</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select name="no_psn" id="no_psn" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $customer['data'] = Customer::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
        ->select('nm_cust','alamat')
        ->get();
        $barang = \App\Barang::All();
        $pemesanan['data'] = Pemesanan::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
        ->select('nm_cust','no_psn')
        ->get();
        // $temp_kirim = Temp_pengiriman::All();

        //No otomatis untuk transaksi pengiriman
        $AWAL = 'DLV';
        $bulanRomawi = array("", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12");
        $noUrutAkhir = \App\Pengiriman::max('no_kirim');
        $no = 1;
        $no_kirim = sprintf("%03s", abs((int)$noUrutAkhir + 1)) . '/' . $AWAL . '/' . $bulanRomawi[date('n')] . '/' . date('Y');

        $pengiriman = Pengiriman::orderBy('no_kirim', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        return view('pengiriman.pengiriman',
            [
                'no_kirim' => $no_kirim,
                'customer' => $customer,
                'barang' => $barang,
                'pemesanan' => $pemesanan,
                // 'temp_kirim' => $temp_kirim,
                'pengiriman' => $pengiriman
            ]
        );
    }

    public function getCustomer($nm_cust="")
    {
        $custData['data'] = Customer::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
        ->select('nm_cust','alamat')
        ->where('nm_cust',$nm_cust)
        ->get();

        return response()->json($custData);
    }

    public function getNoPsn($nm_cust="")
    {
        $noPsnData['data'] = Pemesanan::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
        ->select('nm_cust','no_psn')
        ->where('nm_cust',$nm_cust)
        ->get();

        return response()->json($noPsnData);
    }
```

and this is my AJAX to get the dropdown list

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Department Change
            $('#nm_cust').change(function() {
                // Department id
                var nm_cust = $(this).val();
                // Empty the dropdown
                $('#alamat').find('option').not(':first').remove();
                // AJAX request 
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pengiriman/' + nm_cust,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        var len = 0;
                        if (response['data'] != null) {
                            len = response['data'].length;
                        }
                        if (len > 0) {
                            // Read data and create <option >
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                var nm_cust = response['data'][i].nm_cust;
                                var alamat = response['data'][i].alamat;
                                var option = "<option value='" + alamat + "'>" + alamat +
                                    "</option>";
                                $("#alamat").append(option);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Department Change
            $('#nm_cust').change(function() {
                // Department id
                var alamat = $(this).val();
                // Empty the dropdown
                $('#no_psn').find('option').not(':first').remove();
                // AJAX request 
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'pengiriman/' + alamat,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        var len = 0;
                        if (response['data'] != null) {
                            len = response['data'].length;
                        }
                        if (len > 0) {
                            // Read data and create <option >
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                var alamat = response['data'][i].nm_cust;
                                var no_psn = response['data'][i].no_psn;
                                var option = "<option value='" + no_psn + "'>" + no_psn +
                                    "</option>";
                                $("#no_psn").append(option);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I put that script in the views. Please help me solve this problem or give any clue to fix this.

// I forgot my route to put into this section sorry guys

And this is my routes. so I just change parameter on 3rd route below, which is name('pengiriman.getNoPsn), to /{alamat} depends on my AJAX but still no effect.

```
//pengiriman
    Route::get('/pengiriman', 'PengirimanController@index')->name('pengiriman.pengiriman')->middleware('role:Marketing');
    Route::get('/pengiriman/{nm_cust}', 'PengirimanController@getCustomer')->name('pengiriman.getCustomer')->middleware('role:Marketing');
    Route::get('/pengiriman/{nm_cust}', 'PengirimanController@getNoPsn')->name('pengiriman.getNoPsn')->middleware('role:Marketing');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the **nm_cust** selector twice to get 2nd and 3rd dropdown result. As 2nd and 3rd both dropdown result depending on the **num_cust** selector, so you can keep both under same action. And also ensure that the AJAX URL are correct for both dropdown individually.

**UPDATE:**

Minimize code from your given scenario, as you have issues starting from route to controller to AJAX request. Please Follow the below steps.

Add this route in your route file.

```
Route::get('/pengiriman/psn-cust', 'PengirimanController@getNoPsnAndCustomer')->name('pengiriman.psn-cust')->middleware('role:Marketing');
```

Add this function in your controller file and don not forget to use **Illuminate\Http\Request** class top of your controller file.

```
public function getNoPsnAndCustomer(Request $request) {
    $nm_id = $request->id;

    $custData = Customer::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
        ->select('nm_cust','alamat')
        ->where('nm_cust',$nm_id)
        ->get();

    $noPsnData = Pemesanan::orderby("nm_cust","ASC")
    ->select('nm_cust','no_psn')
    ->where('nm_cust',$nm_id)
    ->get();

    return response()->json(["nm_psn" => $noPsnData, "nm_cust"  => $custData]);
}
```

And use this script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nm_cust').change(function() {

            var nm_id = $(this).val();
            let link = `{{ url('pengiriman/psn-cust')}}`

            $('#alamat').find('option').not(':first').remove();
            $('#no_psn').find('option').not(':first').remove();

            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {id: nm_id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {

                    if(response.nm_psn.length > 0) {
                        let len = response.nm_psn.length;
                        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            let nm_cust = response.nm_psn[i].nm_cust;
                            let alamat = response.nm_psn[i].alamat;
                            let option = "<option value='" + alamat + "'>" + alamat +
                                "</option>";
                            $("#alamat").append(option);
                        }
                    }

                    if(response.nm_cust.length > 0) {
                        let len = response.nm_cust.length;
                        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            let nm_cust = response.nm_cust[i].nm_cust;
                            let alamat = response.nm_cust[i].alamat;
                            let option = "<option value='" + alamat + "'>" + alamat +
                                "</option>";
                            $("#no_psn").append(option);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Oh I see.. so just define the other variable tu put into the 3rd dropdown in one selector. but now the **undefined** just move to the 3rd dropdown and i don't know why. I just followed the instructions you gave. also before I forgot to put my route. Please give me some ways to solve this. thankyou

Comment: @MuhammadHidayat updated the answer, please have a look. As you have issues starting from Route to AJAX request, so I minimize the code from your scenario for. I hope you'll get the process from updated answer.

Comment: Hi.. @Amin Hossain, I have tried the code suggestion you provided and it works! the silly things is, the **undefined** maybe my mistake is on my route, the route is same method and uri. And actually there are still many missed or wrong code before you suggest. Thanks dude I really appreciate it